# Set IDENTITY to begin with Alphabets

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have created a table and set its PK to IDENTITY(1,1).
But I want the PK to begin/start with alphabets e.g CRMSON0, CRMSON1, CRMSON2... and so on.

But I wasn't able to find the solution for Microsoft SQL Server.
on Microsoft website, details I could find were about IDENTITY(seed,increment) or IDENTITY(data type,seed,increment).

Can anyone suggest?

Comment: You can make a primary key that is a string, but it is not efficient space-wise (memory and disk) normally. What is the purpose in doing that?

Comment: May I ask why you think that you  NEED a string PK ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create computed column composed from `CRMSON` + `ID` value:

```
CREATE TABLE #table1 (ID INT IDENTITY(0,1)
                     ,col INT
                     ,col_pk AS CONCAT('CRMSON', ID) PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO #table1(col) VALUES(3), (4);

SELECT *
FROM #table1;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376871)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use

- an `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value
- a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable
  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   CrimsonID AS 'CRIMSON' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10) PERSISTED,
   .... your other columns here....
  )
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `YourTable` without specifying values for `ID` or `CrimsonID`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will **automatically and safely** increase your `ID` value, and `CrimsonID` will contain values like `Crimson1`, `Crimson2`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.

That'll work fine - but as others have already pointed out - I would **NOT** recommend using this column as the **clustered, primary key** - use the `ID` column for that, it's ideally suited for such a task! The `CrimsonID` is bad for mainly two reasons: it's a variable length string, and it's *much too wide* compared to an `int`